# how to save simple xml to binary file and read it using c++

Tags: c++, xml

i have a simple xml text like this:

```
<BTree Version="4">
    <Node Type="SEL" ID="1" Description="rootNode">
        <Node Type="SEL" ID="2" Description="enterNode">
            <Node Type="SEQ" ID="9" Description="Birth">
                <Node Type="ACTION" ID="5073" EditorData="2" Name="TipsNode">
                    <Param Name="Tips" Type="str" Value="drive"/>
                </Node>
            </Node>
        </Node>
        <Node Type="SEL" ID="3" Description="exitNode"/>
        <Node Type="SEL" ID="4" Description="execNode"/>
    </Node>
</BTree>
```

i want to save it as binary file, and then read it.(for some reason, i have to do this)

**i am not going to use [Binary XML protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) such as [Efficient XML Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_XML_Interchange)(an implementation would be [EMIP](http://exip.sourceforge.net/)). because it is too heavy.**

here is what i want:

1.is there any light library(open source,c++) that does this work for me?

2.if there is not, my consideration is implementing this by saving struct to binary file.each node of the xml is a struct. but how to deal with the attribute of the xml noe? i mean
there are different attributes and they are generally optional, how can i define the struct so that there is not memory waste.

Comment: Do you want to save space? Then I suggest to save a compressed xml file via a filestream that does the (de)compression.

Comment: Have a look at 'rapidxml'. Its a fast and small c++ xml parser.

Comment: rapidxml is the way to go with xml/c++, but I heard that json is much faster to parse (rapidjson is the lib)

Comment: @tgmath not only save space, i have to implement this because of my job

Comment: @Johannes `rapidxml` does not support binary file storage